# How can one serve a single Google Sheets cell content to a web page?

Tags: google-sheets

I can embed a Google Docs/Sheet's whole tab/table on a web page.

Is there a simple way to publish the (unformatted) content of a single cell?

Comment: Would like to know this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest workaround I can think of is to create another tab and reference that single cell in `A1`. For example, if the cell you want to publish is cell `C5` on `Sheet1`, create a new sheet `Sheet2` and in cell `A1` put the formula `=Sheet!C5`. You can then delete all of the other columns and rows and embed that  tab. It is not perfect but hopefully will achieve what you want.